# Function definition as qualified id

Tags: c++, namespaces

Why the following code is compiled successfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace B
{
    void foo();
    int i=3;
}

void B::foo()
{
    i=65;
}
int main(){ }
```

and the following is not compiled succefully:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace B
{
    void foo()
    {
        i=65;//error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
    }
    int i=3;
}

int main(){ }
```

I would like to find a reference from the standard clarified this moment.

Comment: **Always** include full compiler warning/error messages. "not compiled successfully" is all but useless.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart UPD

Comment: This is a very common problem, just introduced in the light of namespaces - `i` was declared *after* `foo`, so `foo` doesn't konw about `i`. This has worked this way since the early days of C.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It is pretty clear. But I'm looking for formal reason for that moment (I.e. I'm looking for a corresponding clause into the stadard). Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want quotes 3.4.1 [basic.unqual.lookup]:

> /4 A name used in global scope, outside of any function, class or user-declared namespace, shall be declared before its use in global scope.
>
> /6 A name used in the definition of a function following the function’s declarator-id28 that is a member of namespace N (where, only for the purpose of exposition, N could represent the global scope) shall be declared before its use in the block in which it is used or in one of its enclosing blocks (6.3) or, shall be declared before its use in namespace N or, if N is a nested namespace, shall be declared before its use in one of N’s enclosing namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, `foo` is declared in namespace `B`, so will search for an `i` inside its namespace first (and finds such an `i`, because the implementation of `foo` is AFTER the namespace declaration of `i`). In the second example you are declaring `i` after the definition of `foo`, so `f` does not "see" `i`.

Comment: I'm repeat that `I would like to find a reference from the standard clarified this moment.`

Comment: It is in Sec. 3.3 or 3.4 of the standard, although I cannot find the exact sub-subsection right now.

Comment: Sec. 3.3 define the scopes for declaration in general. There is no something about qualified-id

Comment: Look at 3.4.1 Unqualified name lookup, it may be there. I am pretty sure that either 3.3 or 3.4 should contain the exact specification of your issue.

Comment: @St.Antario: I could dig up a reference for you, but if you don't have it clear that a name in a namespace is only visible **after** the declaration I doubt the reference will help you there... or do you want a reference that lookup inside the function definition will look inside the namespace? (Those are two completely unrelated things)